# C++ : Generic interface design for Database

Tags: c++, postgresql, class-design

I have a class which is used to     create connection with database:

```
class DBHandler
{
public:
    DBHandler();
   ~DBHandler();

    int connect();
    int execQuery( string query);
    string getField( int row, int col);
};
```

Now there is another class which is used to fetch some info from database,

```
class DBManager
{
public:
    DBManager();
   ~DBManager();

   //Approach 1
   string getUsername()
   {
      //create a query here and use     object of DBHandler class to execute it.
   }

   //Approach 2
   string getUsername (struct     QueryDetails& qDetails)
   {
      //create query using fields of structure and execute the query using DBHandler class.
   }
 };
```

Now here is the problem:

1 ) which approach should I follow:

- A) If I use approach 1, then I need to hard code query.
- B) If I use approach 2, then I need to fill structure each time before calling to function getUsername.

2 ) Is there any better solution except these two which would be generic ?

PS : Definition of structure

```
struct QueryDetails
{
    string tableName;
    vector<string> colList;
 ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very broad, and the elements you give do not permit to propose you an objective best answer.

Your approach 1 has the following advantages:

- it is a robust and secure approach :  The queries are written with knowledge of the relevant object
- if the database evolve it's easy to find out (text search) where specific queries are made for the tables, and updated the querying code for your object
- if your object evolves, needless to say, that you'll immediately realise what you have to change on the database side

The main inconvenience, is that you're tightly linked to the database. If tomorrow you change from PostGres to something else, you have to rewrite every query.

Your approach 2 has the following advantages:

- It is very flexible
- If your database change, you have to change only the generic functions.

The inconvenience is that this flexibility bears a lot of risks for the maintenance:  you can't be sure that the correct query is send by the client, and impact assessment of database layout changes are very difficult to assess.

So finally, it's up to you to decide which one would more fit your needs.

I'd personally tend to favour 1. But this is subjective, and I'd anyway introduce an additional layer to make the application code more independent of the database system that implements access to database.

However, depending on your need, a greater flexibility could be of advantage. For instance, if your class is in fact meant to be a middle layer for other calsses to fetch their own data,  then approach 2 could be the best option.

Comment: Yes you are right, my DBManager class is the middle layer between DBHandler and other class which needs some info from database. Though both solutions are specific to some points, I am looking for a generic interface for the same.

Comment: @SonuMaddeshia In this case alternative 2 is definitively the option to go for.